# $cookies.get is not a function - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies, missing-cookies

Designed two pages. Cookies is not set and showing error.

CDN:

```js
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

**Main Page** - Set Cookies / cookies is not set

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
 app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$cookies', '$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location',  function($cookies,$scope, $http,  $window, $location) {
  $cookies.put('username', 'name');  
}
```

**Second Page** - Get Cookies

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngTable', 'ngCookies' , 'ngResource']);
  app.controller('AccountMappingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$cookies', 'NgTableParams',  function($scope, $http, $filter, $cookies, NgTableParams) {  
    $scope.UsernameCookies = $cookies.get("username");
}
```

It is showing $cookies.get is not working.

Comment: What exactly is the error message you're seeing?

Comment: In first page i dint get any error. But while I am checking the via IF statement it is saying cookies not set. $cookies.put('username', 'name');

            if($cookies.get('username'))
            {
              alert("Success");
            }
            else
            {
              alert("No Cookies");
            }

Comment: in the second page, I am getting $cookies.get is not a function error.

Comment: Maybe because `'$filter'` is missing from the array on that second page?

Comment: var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngTable', 'ngCookies' , 'ngResource']);
   app.controller('AccountMappingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$cookies', '$filter', 'NgTableParams',  function($scope, $http, $cookies, $filter, NgTableParams) {  
   It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
$scope.UsernameCookies = $cookies[username];
```

if will not work inject '$cookieStore' in your controller and try following:

```
$cookieStore.get('username')
```